# Drawing an 3D Cube with Pure CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to transform this cube, see code below, to this one which you can see on the pictures, but I don't get it.

### Actual Result:

[image: Current Cube]

### CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
    .cube-wrap {
        -webkit-perspective: 800px;
        -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
        -moz-perspective: 800px;
        -moz-perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
        -ms-perspective: 800px;
        -ms-perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
        perspective: 800px;
        perspective-origin: 50% 100px;
    }
    .cube {
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -webkit-animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
        -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -moz-animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
        -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -ms-animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        animation: spin 5s infinite linear;
    }
    .cube div {
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px rgba(125, 125, 125, 0.8);
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 100px;
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        font-family: sans-serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .depth div.back-pane {
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(180deg);
        -moz-transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(180deg);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(180deg);
        transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(180deg);
    }
    .depth div.right-pane {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(100px);
        -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
        -moz-transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(100px);
        -moz-transform-origin: top right;
        -ms-transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(100px);
        -ms-transform-origin: top right;
        transform: rotateY(-270deg) translateX(100px);
        transform-origin: top right;
    }
    .depth div.left-pane {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px);
        -webkit-transform-origin: center left;
        -moz-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px);
        -moz-transform-origin: center left;
        -ms-transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px);
        -ms-transform-origin: center left;
        transform: rotateY(270deg) translateX(-100px);
        transform-origin: center left;
    }
    .depth div.top-pane {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px);
        -webkit-transform-origin: top center;
        -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px);
        -moz-transform-origin: top center;
        -ms-transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px);
        -ms-transform-origin: top center;
        transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(-100px);
        transform-origin: top center;
    }
    .depth div.bottom-pane {
        -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(100px);
        -webkit-transform-origin: bottom center;
        -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(100px);
        -moz-transform-origin: bottom center;
        -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(100px);
        -ms-transform-origin: bottom center;
        transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(100px);
        transform-origin: bottom center;
    }
    .depth div.front-pane {
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
        -moz-transform: translateZ(100px);
        -ms-transform: translateZ(100px);
        transform: translateZ(100px);
    }
</style>
```

### HTML

```
 <div id="page">
   <div id="contentHolder">
     <div style="height: 100px; margin-top: 40px;">
        <div class="cube-wrap">
           <div class="cube depth">
             <div class="front-pane"></div>
             <div class="back-pane"></div>
             <div class="top-pane"></div>
             <div class="bottom-pane"></div>
             <div class="left-pane"></div>
             <div class="right-pane"></div>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

#### Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YT6hd/

### Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: create a fiddle pls (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Thanks for redesign my question!

Comment: You can find a tutorial [here...](http://davidwalsh.name/css-cube) [or here...](http://cssdeck.com/labs/simple-css3-3d-cube) [here too...](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/cube.html) You can use javascript to rotate a cube [here...](http://www.seanslinsky.com/2012/05/rotating-3d-cube-css3-javascript) Have you even tried searching on how to do it?

Comment: I don't need rotation, it should look like the image. It sjould look like a box where we can put things in...

Answer (score 1):

This should help, you'll have to play around with the values a little bit:

http://jsfiddle.net/YT6hd/1/

```
.cube.depth {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(45deg);
}

.cube-wrap {
    -webkit-perspective: 8000px;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 20% 2000px;
}
```

Of course you'll need all the browser prefixes, I use chrome so I added -webkit-